# Update jLabel on button click

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
 private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    jLabel6.setText("Please wait");
    Cursor hourglassCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
    setCursor(hourglassCursor);
    //Program code
    Cursor normalCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
    setCursor(normalCursor);
    jLabel6.setText("");
 }
```

I have this under `actionPerformed` method. I have couple of updates to the `jLabel`. The first `jLabel` text update ("Please wait") isn't shown on the screen on button click. After all the process is done `jLabel` is set to an empty string.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: you have to run it on another thread.

Comment: I would like to update it couple of times. 
Before all the process is done, jLabel should display please wait and once all the process is done it should be an empty string

Comment: You're gonna want to look at a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to update with a delay

Comment: Or even a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). You could take advantage of the `done()` method.

Comment: Another option could be to implement an asynchronous call that handles whatever logic you need to run. What you would then do is change the label to "Please wait" and set the cursor prior to making the call and in the async callback's onSuccess method you would change it to "" and reset the cursor

Comment: Could you please tell me how to implement asynchronous call? @BrandonLaidig

Comment: @NikithaReddy yes, I'll write up an answer explaining it

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs :)

Comment: I have implemented this using thread @chalithalawanga 
But I would like to know the asynchronous method as well

Comment: @NikithaReddy I have added my solution. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
public void run() {
    Cursor hourglassCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
    setCursor(hourglassCursor);
    //Program code
    Cursor normalCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
    setCursor(normalCursor);
    }
};
updateThread.start();
```

I have included this under a separate thread and then the below code for using invokeLater() of SwingUtilities

```
public void updateProgress(String updateString) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            jLabel6.setText(updateString);
        }
    });
}
```

I called updateProgress() method as per my requirement.

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I should mention it would likely be easier to just use a separate thread, but if you're interested in using an async call the following should work

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    jLabel6.setText("Please wait");
    setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    doStuff();
}
```

Where `doStuff()` is defined as follows using [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/) async annotation

```
@Async
private void doStuff() {
    //do whatever logic you need to here
    jLabel6.setText("");
    setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
}
```

What this does is make the `doStuff()` method asynchronous and the reason we put the logic to change the label and cursor back within the method itself is that the method will run in a new thread separate of the main thread.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. Simple annotation makes everything work. Learned something new today.